# Adding attributes to an XML node

Tags: c#, xml

How can I create an xml file dynamically, with the following structure?

```
<Login>
  <id userName="Tushar" passWord="Tushar">
      <Name>Tushar</Name>
      <Age>24</Age>
  </id>
</Login>
```

I am not able to create the attributes inside the `id` tag (i.e. userName="" and  passWord="").

I am using C# in a windows application.

Some Important namespace that you might require is

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
```

Answer (score 94):

Well `id` isn't really the root node: `Login` is.

It should just be a case of specifying the attributes (not tags, btw) using [`XmlElement.SetAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.setattribute.aspx). You haven't specified how you're creating the file though - whether you're using XmlWriter, the DOM, or any other XML API.

If you could give an example of the code you've got which isn't working, that would help a lot. In the meantime, here's some code which creates the file you described:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Login");
        XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("id");
        id.SetAttribute("userName", "Tushar");
        id.SetAttribute("passWord", "Tushar");
        XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("Name");
        name.InnerText = "Tushar";
        XmlElement age = doc.CreateElement("Age");
        age.InnerText = "24";

        id.AppendChild(name);
        id.AppendChild(age);
        root.AppendChild(id);
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        doc.Save("test.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 46):

There is also a way to add an attribute to an `XmlNode` object, that can be useful in some cases.

I found this other method on [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx).

```
using System.Xml;

[...]

//Assuming you have an XmlNode called node
XmlNode node;

[...]

//Get the document object
XmlDocument doc = node.OwnerDocument;

//Create a new attribute
XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("attributeName");
attr.Value = "valueOfTheAttribute";

//Add the attribute to the node     
node.Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr);

[...]
```

Answer (score 34):

The latest and supposedly greatest way to construct the XML is by using LINQ to XML:

```
using System.Xml.Linq

       var xmlNode =
            new XElement("Login",
                         new XElement("id",
                             new XAttribute("userName", "Tushar"),
                             new XAttribute("password", "Tushar"),
                             new XElement("Name", "Tushar"),
                             new XElement("Age", "24")
                         )
            );
       xmlNode.Save("Tushar.xml");
```

Supposedly this way of coding should be easier, as the code closely resembles the output (which Jon's example above does not). However, I found that while coding this relatively easy example I was prone to lose my way between the cartload of comma's that you have to navigate among. Visual studio's auto spacing of code does not help either.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the Class **XmlAttribute**.

Eg:

```
XmlAttribute attr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("userName");
attr.Value = "Tushar";

node.Attributes.Append(attr);
```

Comment: can you please put some explanation?

Answer (score 5):

If you serialize the object that you have, you can do something like this by using "*System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute*" on every property that you want to be specified as an attribute in your model, which in my opinion is a lot easier:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class UserNode
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }         
 }

 public class LoginNode 
 {
    public UserNode Id { get; set; }
 }
```

Then you just serialize to XML an instance of LoginNode called "Login", and that's it!

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml) you have a few examples to serialize and object to XML, but I would suggest to create an extension method in order to be reusable for other objects.

Comment: What would you do if the Node you're trying to add an attribute to is not an object, but a string?