# Serialize an object to XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a C# class that I have inherited. I have successfully "built" the object. But I need to serialize the object to XML. Is there an easy way to do it?

It looks like the class has been set up for serialization, but I'm not sure how to get the XML representation. My class definition looks like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.domain.com/test")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.domain.com/test", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class MyObject
{
  ...
}
```

Here is what I thought I could do, but it doesn't work:

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
// Set o properties
string xml = o.ToString();
```

How do I get the XML representation of this object?

Comment: Please see also: [XML Serialization and Deserialization on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487571/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)

Comment: I developed a simple library to do achieve this: https://github.com/aishwaryashiva/SaveXML

Answer (score 597, accepted):

You have to use XmlSerializer for XML serialization. Below is a sample snippet.

```
 XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
 var subReq = new MyObject();
 var xml = "";

 using(var sww = new StringWriter())
 {
     using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
     {
         xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, subReq);
         xml = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
     }
 }
```

As per @kiquenet request for generic class:

```
public class MySerializer<T> where T : class
{
    public static string Serialize(T obj)
    {
        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var sww = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sww) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
            {
                xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, obj);
                return sww.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
string xmlMessage = MySerializer<MyClass>.Serialize(myObj);
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly well without the line `XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);`

Comment: To have serialized object formatted do: `XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sww) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };` instead of `XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);`

Comment: Since `XmlWriter` encapsulates the `StringWriter` you don't need to dispose both (the first using is redundant), right? I'm assuming `XmlWriter` takes care of dispose it...

Comment: There is no reason to have both a `StringWriter` and a `XmlWriter`. you just need to use the `StringWriter` as the XmlSerializer already outputs data as xml.

Comment: @talles `XmlWriter` is not encapsulating the `StringWriter`, it is utilizing your passed-in `StringWriter`and has no expectation/responsibility to dispose of it. Further `StringWriter` is outside `XmlWriter`'s scope, you may still want it when `XmlWriter` is disposed, it would be poor behavior for `XmlWriter` to dispose your `StringWriter`. As a general rule, if you declare something that needs disposing you're responsible for disposing of it. And implicit to that rule, anything you don't declare yourself you shouldn't dispose. So both `using`s are necessary.

Comment: using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

Comment: @talles This is now verifiable in the .NET Core codebase on Github. XmlWriter does not dispose of the underlying StringWriter.

Comment: Using Generics ?

Comment: check updated answer @Kiquenet

Answer (score 132):

I modified mine to return a string rather than use a ref variable like below.

```
public static string Serialize<T>(this T value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    try
    {
        var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("An error occurred", ex);
    }
}
```

Its usage would be like this:

```
var xmlString = obj.Serialize();
```

Comment: very nice solution , I like the way you implemented this as an extention method

Comment: One thing I'd suggest here: remove the try...catch block. It doesn't give you any benefit and just obfuscates the error that's being thrown.

Comment: Don't you also need using on the stringwriter? eg: using(var stringWriter = new StringWriter())

Comment: @jammycakes No! When you throw a new `Exception` there, you have extended the StackTrace with the method "Serialize<>".

Comment: @user2190035 surely if it were to break within extension method the stack trace would start there? "Extending the stack trace" with the try does seem unnecessary?

Comment: @user2190035 were you replying to the wrong person?

Comment: Remarkable. This `Serialize<T>(this T value)` part is so useful. Never thought about extension methods and generics together before.

Comment: Here lies the power of C#, using extension method together with Generics.

Answer (score 48):

The following function can be copied to any object to add an XML save function using the System.Xml namespace.

```
/// <summary>
/// Saves to an xml file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="FileName">File path of the new xml file</param>
public void Save(string FileName)
{
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

To create the object from the saved file, add the following function and replace [ObjectType] with the object type to be created.

```
/// <summary>
/// Load an object from an xml file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="FileName">Xml file name</param>
/// <returns>The object created from the xml file</returns>
public static [ObjectType] Load(string FileName)
{
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FileName))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof([ObjectType]));
        return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as [ObjectType];
    }
}
```

Comment: `writer.Flush()` is redundant in a `using` block - `writer`'s `Dispose()` method will flush it for you.

Comment: My experience has found that isn't true.  With larger data, the using statement will dispose the stream before the buffer is cleared.  I 100% recommend explicitly calling flush.

Comment: writer.Flush() is NOT redundant, it MUST be there. Without Flush, it can happen that part of data is still in StreamWriter buffer and the file gets disposed and some data are missing.

Comment: I like your code very much: short and neat. 

My problem is with the copying the functions again and again to different classes: is not it code duplication? The other answers suggest generic library with template extension methods, that I would embrace.


What do you think?

Answer (score 36):

Extension class:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MyProj.Extensions
{
    public static class XmlExtension
    {
        public static string Serialize<T>(this T value)
        {
            if (value == null) return string.Empty;

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter,new XmlWriterSettings{Indent = true}))
                {
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
                    return stringWriter.ToString();
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Foo foo = new Foo{MyProperty="I have been serialized"};

string xml = foo.Serialize();
```

Just reference the namespace holding your extension method in the file you would like to use it in and it'll work (in my example it would be: `using MyProj.Extensions;`)

Note that if you want to make the extension method specific to only a particular class(eg., `Foo`), you can replace the `T` argument in the extension method, eg.

`public static string Serialize(this Foo value){...}`

Answer (score 31):

You can use the function like below to get serialized XML from any object.

```
public static bool Serialize<T>(T value, ref string serializeXml)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);

        xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, value);

        serializeXml = stringWriter.ToString();

        writer.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can call this from the client.

Answer (score 31):

All upvoted answers above are correct. This is just simplest version:

```
private string Serialize(Object o)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        new XmlSerializer(o.GetType()).Serialize(writer, o);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

To serialize an object, do:

```
 using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false))
 {
     XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(your_object_type));
     mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, objectToSerialize);
 }
```

Also remember that for XmlSerializer to work, you need a parameterless constructor.

Comment: This was driving me nuts. I couldn't figure out why it was always blank. Then realized I didn't have a constructor with no parameters after reading your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

I will start with the copy answer of Ben Gripka:

```
public void Save(string FileName)
{
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

I used this code earlier. But reality showed that this solution is a bit problematic. Usually most of programmers just serialize setting on save and deserialize settings on load. This is an optimistic scenario. Once the serialization failed, because of some reason, the file is partly written, XML file is not complete and it is invalid. In consequence XML deserialization does not work and your application may crash on start. If the file is not huge, I suggest first serialize object to `MemoryStream` then write the stream to the File. This case is especially important if there is some complicated custom serialization. You can never test all cases.

```
public void Save(string fileName)
{
    //first serialize the object to memory stream,
    //in case of exception, the original file is not corrupted
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);    
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        writer.Flush();

        //if the serialization succeed, rewrite the file.
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

The deserialization in real world scenario should count with corrupted serialization file, it happens sometime. Load function provided by Ben Gripka is fine.

```
public static [ObjectType] Load(string fileName)
{
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof([ObjectType]));
        return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as [ObjectType];        
    }    
}
```

And it could be wrapped by some recovery scenario. It is suitable for settings files or other files which can be deleted in case of problems.

```
public static [ObjectType] LoadWithRecovery(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        return Load(fileName);
    }
    catch(Excetion)
    {
        File.Delete(fileName); //delete corrupted settings file
        return GetFactorySettings();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible for the process to be interrupted while writing the MemoryStream to a file, for example by a power shutdown?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can avoid it by writing settings to a temporary file and then replace the original.

Answer (score 9):

It's a little bit more complicated than calling the `ToString` method of the class, but not much.

Here's a simple drop-in function you can use to serialize any type of object. It returns a string containing the serialized XML contents:

```
public string SerializeObject(object obj)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
        serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Position = 0;
        xmlDoc.Load(ms);
        return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on above solutions, here comes a extension class which you can use to serialize and deserialize any object. Any other XML attributions are up to you.

Just use it like this:

```
        string s = new MyObject().Serialize(); // to serialize into a string
        MyObject b = s.Deserialize<MyObject>();// deserialize from a string



internal static class Extensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string value)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(value));
    }

    public static string Serialize<T>(this T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the Usage: 
What should Deserialize return for string = "" ?

Comment: I think I cooked up the solution, I am a copy paste programmer :)
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529611/c-sharp-create-new-t
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string value) where T : new()
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        if (value == "") return new T();
        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(value));
    }

Answer (score 8):

I have a simple way to serialize an object to XML using C#, it works great and it's highly reusable. I know this is an older thread, but I wanted to post this because someone may find this helpful to them.

Here is how I call the method:

```
var objectToSerialize = new MyObject();
var xmlString = objectToSerialize.ToXmlString();
```

Here is the class that does the work:

**Note: Since these are extension methods they need to be in a static class.**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public static class XmlTools
{
    public static string ToXmlString<T>(this T input)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            input.ToXml(writer);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }

    private static void ToXml<T>(this T objectToSerialize, StringWriter writer)
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a good tutorial on how to do this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813)

You should basically use `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` class to do this.

Answer (score 5):

my work code. Returns **utf8** xml enable empty namespace.

```
// override StringWriter
public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;
}

private string GenerateXmlResponse(Object obj)
{    
    Type t = obj.GetType();

    var xml = "";

    using (StringWriter sww = new Utf8StringWriter())
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
        {
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            // add empty namespace
            ns.Add("", "");
            XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(t);
            xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
            xml = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
        }
    }
    return xml;
}
```

Example returns response Yandex api payment Aviso url:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><paymentAvisoResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" performedDatetime="2017-09-01T16:22:08.9747654+07:00" code="0" shopId="54321" invoiceId="12345" orderSumAmount="10643" />
```

Comment: Hi @dev-siberia, I am using your code but it returns xml in string form means everything in double quote.

Answer (score 3):

```
    string FilePath = ConfigurationReader.FileLocation;   //Getting path value from web.config            
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Devices)); //typeof(object)
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.Serialize(memStream, lstDevices);//lstdevices : I take result as a list.
            FileStream file = new FileStream(folderName + "\\Data.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite); //foldername:Specify the path to store the xml file
            memStream.WriteTo(file);
            file.Close();
```

You can create and store the result as xml file in the desired location.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can add this method to your object:

```
    public void Save(string filename)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            ser.Serialize(stream, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic code that will help serializing the C# objects into xml:

```
using System;

public class clsPerson
{
  public  string FirstName;
  public  string MI;
  public  string LastName;
}

class class1
{ 
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      clsPerson p=new clsPerson();
      p.FirstName = "Jeff";
      p.MI = "A";
      p.LastName = "Price";
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
      x.Serialize(Console.Out, p);
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you cite source of this code: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815813/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-by-using-visual-c

Answer (score 1):

```
public string ObjectToXML(object input)
{
    try
    {
        var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(input.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, input);
        return stringwriter.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
            ex = ex.InnerException;

        return "Could not convert: " + ex.Message;
    }
}

//Usage
var res = ObjectToXML(obj)
```

You need to use following classes:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic object serializer:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace System.Xml.Serialization
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes and deserializes <typeparamref name="T"/> objects into XML documents.
    /// Allows you to control the process of encoding objects in XML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Object type.</typeparam>
    public static class XmlSerializer<T>
    {
        private static readonly XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        private static readonly XmlWriterSettings _defaultWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            CheckCharacters = false
            CloseOutput=false
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            indent=true,
            IndentChars = "\t",
            NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
            NewLineChars = "\r\n",
            NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
            NewLineOnAttributes = false,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = false
        };
        private static readonly XmlReaderSettings _defaultReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            CheckCharacters = false
            CloseInput=false
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit,
            IgnoreComments = true,
            IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true,
            IgnoreWhitespace=true,
            LineNumberOffset = 0
            LinePositionOffset = 0
            MaxCharactersFromEntities = 0,
            MaxCharactersInDocument = 0,
            NameTable = null
            // Schemas = null, // ???
            ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.None,
            ValidationType = ValidationType. None,
            XmlResolver = null
        }; 
        
         /// <summary>
         /// Default character encoding.
         /// </summary>
         public static Encoding DefaultEncoding => Encoding.UTF8;

         /// <summary>
         /// Default settings for the <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance being created.
         /// </summary>
         public static XmlWriterSettings DefaultXmlWriterSettings => _defaultWriterSettings.Clone();

         /// <summary>
         /// Default settings for the <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance that is created.
         /// </summary>
         public static XmlReaderSettings DefaultXmlReaderSettings => _defaultReaderSettings.Clone();    

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and returns the XML document as a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        public static string Serialize(T o)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
                _serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, o, (XmlSerializerNamespaces)null);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and returns the XML document as a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlWriterSettings"/>.
        /// </param>
        public static string Serialize(T o, XmlWriterSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = _defaultWriterSettings;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
                _serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, o, (XmlSerializerNamespaces)null);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="TextWriter" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textWriter">
        /// <see cref="TextWriter" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        public static void Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, T o)
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter))
                _serializer.Serialize(textWriter, o, (XmlSerializerNamespaces)null);
        } 
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="TextWriter" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textWriter">
        /// <see cref="TextWriter" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlWriterSettings"/>.
        /// </param>
        public static void Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, T o, XmlWriterSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = _defaultWriterSettings;
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                _serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, o, (XmlSerializerNamespaces)null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="TextWriter" /> and references to the given namespaces.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textWriter">
        /// <see cref="TextWriter" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="namespaces">
        /// <see cref="XmlSerializerNamespaces" /> Contains the namespaces for the generated XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during serialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static void Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, T o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter))
                _serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, o, namespaces);
        } 
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="TextWriter" /> and references to the given namespaces.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textWriter">
        /// <see cref="TextWriter" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="namespaces">
        /// <see cref="XmlSerializerNamespaces" /> Contains the namespaces for the generated XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlWriterSettings"/>.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during serialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static void Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, T o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, XmlWriterSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = _defaultWriterSettings;
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                _serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, o, namespaces);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="Stream" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">
        /// <see cref="Stream" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during serialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static void Serialize(Stream stream, T o)
        {
            _serializer.Serialize(stream, o, (XmlSerializerNamespaces)null);
        } 
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="Stream" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">
        /// <see cref="Stream" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlWriterSettings"/>.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during serialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static void Serialize(Stream stream, T o, XmlWriterSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = _defaultWriterSettings;
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, settings.Encoding))
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings))
                _serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, o, (XmlSerializerNamespaces) null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="Stream" /> refers to the given namespaces.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">
        /// <see cref="Stream" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="namespaces">
        /// <see cref="XmlSerializerNamespaces" /> The object is referenced.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during serialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static void Serialize(Stream stream, T o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
        {
            _serializer.Serialize(stream, o, namespaces);
        } 
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="Stream" /> refers to the given namespaces.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">
        /// <see cref="Stream" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="namespaces">
        /// <see cref="XmlSerializerNamespaces" /> The object is referenced.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlWriterSettings"/>.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during serialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static void Serialize(Stream stream, T o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, XmlWriterSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = _defaultWriterSettings;
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, settings.Encoding))
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings))
                _serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, o, namespaces);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="XmlWriter" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlWriter">
        /// <see cref="XmlWriter" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// the settings of the current <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance are used.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during serialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static void Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, T o, XmlWriterSettings settings = null)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = settings == null ? xmlWriter : XmlWriter.Create(xmlWriter, settings))
                _serializer.Serialize(writer, o, (XmlSerializerNamespaces)null); 
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="XmlWriter" /> and references to the given namespaces.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlWriter">
        /// <see cref="XmlWriter" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// Instance <see cref="object" /> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="namespaces">
        /// <see cref="XmlSerializerNamespaces" /> The object is referenced.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// the settings of the current <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance are used.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during serialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static void Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, T o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, XmlWriterSettings settings = null)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = settings == null ? xmlWriter : XmlWriter.Create(xmlWriter, settings))
                _serializer.Serialize(writer, o, namespaces);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the specified object and writes the XML document to a file using the specified <typeparamref name="T"/> and references the specified namespaces and encoding style.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlWriter">
        /// <see cref="XmlWriter" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">Object to serialize.</param>
        /// <param name="namespaces">
        /// <see cref="XmlSerializerNamespaces" /> The object is referenced.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="encodingStyle">
        /// The encoding style of the serialized XML.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// the settings of the current <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance are used.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during serialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static void Serialize(
            XmlWriter xmlWriter,
            T o
            XmlSerializerNamespaces,
            string encodingStyle,
            XmlWriterSettings settings = null)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = settings == null ? xmlWriter : XmlWriter.Create(xmlWriter, settings))
                _serializer.Serialize(writer, o, namespaces, encodingStyle, (string)null);
        } 
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given <typeparamref name="T"/> and writes the XML document to a file using the given <see cref="XmlWriter" />, XML namespaces, and encoding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlWriter">
        /// <see cref="XmlWriter" /> Used to write an XML document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="o">Object to serialize.</param>
        /// <param name="namespaces">
        /// An instance of <see langword="XmlSerializaerNamespaces" /> containing the namespaces and prefixes used.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="encodingStyle">
        /// The encoding used in the document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="id">
        /// For SOAP encoded messages, a base is used to generate identifier attributes.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// the settings of the current <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance are used.
        /// </param>
        public static void Serialize(
            XmlWriter xmlWriter,
            T o
            XmlSerializerNamespaces,
            string encodingStyle,
            string id,
            XmlWriterSettings settings = null)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = settings == null ? xmlWriter : XmlWriter.Create(xmlWriter, settings))
                _serializer.Serialize(writer, o, namespaces, encodingStyle, id);
        } 
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the XML document contained in the specified string.
        /// </summary>
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlReaderSettings"/>.</param>
        /// <returns> The deserialized object <typeparamref name="T"/>. </returns>
        public static T Deserialize(string text)
        {
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(text))
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
                return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the XML document contained in the specified string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">String containing the XML document.</param>
        /// <param name="settings"> Settings for the new <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlReaderSettings"/>.</param>
        /// <returns> The deserialized object <typeparamref name="T"/>. </returns>
        public static T Deserialize(string text, XmlReaderSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = _defaultReaderSettings;
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(text))
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
                return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the XML document contained in the specified <see cref="Stream" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">
        /// <see cref="Stream" /> Containing the XML document to deserialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Deserialized object <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </returns>
        public static T Deserialize(Stream stream)
        {
                return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        } 
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the XML document contained in the specified <see cref="Stream" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">
        /// <see cref="Stream" /> Containing the XML document to deserialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">Settings for the new <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlReaderSettings"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Deserialized object <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </returns>
        public static T Deserialize(Stream stream, XmlReaderSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = _defaultReaderSettings;
            using(XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
                return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the XML document contained in the specified <see cref="TextReader" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textReader">
        /// <see cref="TextReader" /> The containing XML document to deserialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Deserialized object <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during deserialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static T Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
        {
            return (T) _serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the XML document contained in the specified <see cref="TextReader" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textReader">
        /// <see cref="TextReader" /> The containing XML document to deserialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">Settings for the new <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlReaderSettings"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Deserialized object <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during deserialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static T Deserialize(TextReader textReader, XmlReaderSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = _defaultReaderSettings;
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
                return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        } 
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the XML document contained in the specified <see cref="XmlReader" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlReader">
        /// <see cref="XmlReader" /> The containing XML document to deserialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">Settings for the new <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// current instance settings are used <see cref="XmlReader" />.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Deserialized object <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during deserialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static T Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, XmlReaderSettings settings = null)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = settings == null ? xmlReader : XmlReader.Create(xmlReader, settings))
                return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the XML document contained in the specified <see cref="XmlReader" /> and allows you to override events that occur during deserialization.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlReader">
        /// <see cref="XmlReader" /> The containing document to deserialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="events">
        /// Class instance <see cref="XmlDeserializationEvents" />.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">Settings for the new <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// current instance settings are used <see cref="XmlReader" />.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Deserialized object <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </returns>
        public static T Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, XmlDeserializationEvents events, XmlReaderSettings settings = null)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = settings == null ? xmlReader : XmlReader.Create(xmlReader, settings))
                return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(reader, (string)null, events);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the XML document contained in the specified <see cref="XmlReader" /> and encoding style.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlReader">
        /// <see cref="XmlReader" /> The containing XML document to deserialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="encodingStyle">
        /// The encoding style of the serialized XML.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">Settings for the new <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// current instance settings are used <see cref="XmlReader" />.</param>
        /// <returns>The deserialized object.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
        /// An error occurred during deserialization.
        /// The original exception is accessible using the <see cref="P:System.Exception.InnerException" /> property.
        /// </exception>
        public static T Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, string encodingStyle, XmlReaderSettings settings = null)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = settings == null ? xmlReader : XmlReader.Create(xmlReader, settings))
                return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(reader, encodingStyle);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the object using the data contained in the specified <see cref="XmlReader" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlReader">
        /// An instance of the <see cref="XmlReader" /> class used to read the document.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="encodingStyle">Encoding used.</param>
        /// <param name="events">
        /// Class instance <see cref="XmlDeserializationEvents" />.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">Settings for the new <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance. If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// current instance settings are used <see cref="XmlReader" />.</param>
        /// <returns>The deserialized object <typeparamref name="T"/>.</returns>
        public static object Deserialize(
            xmlReader xmlReader,
            string encodingStyle,
            XmlDeserializationEvents events,
            XmlReaderSettings settings = null)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = settings == null ? xmlReader : XmlReader.Create(xmlReader, settings))
                return _serializer.Deserialize(reader, encodingStyle, events);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a value indicating whether this <see cref="XmlSerializer" /> can deserialize the specified XML document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlReader">
        /// <see cref="XmlReader" /> Pointing to the document to deserialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// <see langword="true" /> If this <see cref="XmlSerializer" /> can deserialize an object, <see cref="XmlReader" /> indicates; otherwise, <see langword="false" />.
        /// </returns>
        public static bool CanDeserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
        {
            return _serializer.CanDeserialize(xmlReader);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It might be too late to party but there is serialization with only user defined Namespaces:

```
public static string XmlSerialize<T>(this T obj) where T : class
        {
            Type serialType = typeof(T);
            var xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(serialType);

            XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true };
            

            var Namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new XmlQualifiedName[] {           
            new XmlQualifiedName(string.Empty,  GetXmlNameSpace(serialType) ?? string.Empty )


        });
 private static string GetXmlNameSpace(Type target)
        {
            XmlRootAttribute attribute = (XmlRootAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(target, typeof(XmlRootAttribute));
            return attribute == null ? null : attribute.Namespace;
        }
```

And defined namespace in the custom class

```
 [XmlRoot("IdentityTerminal",Namespace = "http://my-name-space/XMLSchema")]
   
    public class IdentityTerminal
    {
    }
```

This code allows to user only user defined namespaces and omit default ones.