# What are the use cases of having new() in "public T SomeMethod<T>(string item) where T : new();"

Tags: c#, oop, generics, design-patterns

I am trying to identify `various uses cases` of using `new()` in statement

```
public T SomeMethod<T>(string item) where T : new();
```

I know compiler will ensure that `T` must have a default constructor. But in what all scenario this is helpful.

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529611/c-sharp-create-new-t)

Comment: it's useful any time your generic method needs to create an instance of the generic type. beyond that, this question is way to broad to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MSDN's own page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) on `where T : new()` lists the most common use case:

> Apply the new constraint to a type parameter when your generic class creates new instances of the type, as shown in the following example:

```
class ItemFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GetNewItem()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

The constraint also requires that the parameterless constructor be *public*.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful if your generic method/class will have to create an instance of the given type. If you had a method that created a generic type:

```
public void DoWork<T>() where T : new() {
    var thing = new T();
}
```

Vs:

```
public void DoWork<T>() {
    var thing = new T(); - runtime says "wtf are you doing? i cant create a 
                           new T because T might not have a public  
                           parameterless constructor"
}
```

Comment: It's not possible for "T" to not have a constructor. private/protected/public... with/without parameter.. or default contructor. But there is always one, at least.

Comment: @Amby - nice catch. Was walking and typing, and didn't read over before posting.

Answer (score 2):

It's helpful if anywhere in your code you need to create a new instance of T - for example, in a generic factory method. If you don't ensure a parameterless constructor, your code can never create an instance (since you don't know what the constructor signature will look like).

Answer (score 0):

```
public T SomeMethod<T>(string item) where T : new();
```

Constraints "T" to be type having default (parameterless) contructor.

You won't be able to use this type (would fail to compile)

```
public class CustomTypeA{
     public CustomTypeA(int count){}
}
```

while this one is allowed,

```
public class CustomTypeB{
}
```

and this one also,

```
public class CustomTypeC{
     public CustomTypeC(){}
}
```

Also note, this type of constrain would accept all Struct T's (int,double etc). Because structs always have a default contructor.

Given these possiblitis,
It is useful : 1) when you want to constraint to above list.
2) when you want to instantiate (call its constructor) such type without using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The point of this constraint is that the compiler will guarantee that any type you specify for `T` will have a public parameterless constructor, allowing this code to work:

```
var instance = new T();
```

Note, however, that the above code will in fact turn into a call to `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`, which means that the guarantee is all you get. You *could* call the `Activator.CreateInstance` method yourself, however you have no guarantee that the type actually have a parameterless constructor unless you add the constraint.