# Generically Casting object to it's 'real' type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have shared validation logic which largely depends on custom attributes, so I need to check that for each type.

An instance (to check against) is fetched for each validation subscriber:

```
var instance = this.ValidationProvider.GetInstanceForSubscriber(validationSubscriber);
```

Where `validationSubscriber` is an enum with these values:

> Person, 
>   Checks

At this time, `GetInstanceForSubscriber` returns an instance of type object:

```
public object GetInstanceForSubscriber(ValidationSubscribers validationSubscriber)
{
    switch (validationSubscriber)
    {
        case ValidationSubscribers.Person:
            return new Person();
        case ValidationSubscribers.Checks:
            return new Checks();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

After calling this method, I check the type:

```
var instanceType = instance.GetType();
```

And then, I read the (custom) attributes:

```
var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

I then return a list of `IEnumerable<PropertyAttribute>` which contains only my custom attributes, limiting the validation scale to what's necessary only (which is FYI, because not very relevant for this question).

**The issue**

As `instance` is of type object, it does not contain any of my custom attributes (logically), so I need to cast it to the correct Class Type.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have exact matching names for Enum values and class names?

Comment: Why do you bellieve it doesnt contain your attributes?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta: No, and I'm not in favor of that because that could/would become hard to maintain (and very untrustworthy).

Comment: @CSharpie: The `var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true)` line returns a 0 items list, while it works just fine for the actual type. Which makes sense, because `object` wouldn't have my custom attributes.

Comment: If you use instance.GetType() it should never return typeof(object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to modify your design by introducing interface.

```
public interface ICustomAttribute
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyAttribute> GetCustomAttributes(true);
}

class Person:ICustomAttribute
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyAttribute> GetCustomAttributes(true)
    {
         //Validation logic here for Person entity.
         //Encapsulate your entity level logic here.
          return propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    }
}

class Check:ICustomAttribute
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyAttribute> GetCustomAttributes(true)
    {
         //Validation logic here for CHECK entity
         //Encapsulate your entity level logic here.
          return propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    }
}

public ICustomAttribute GetInstanceForSubscriber(ValidationSubscribers validationSubscriber)
{
    //Use dependency injection to eliminate this if possible
    switch (validationSubscriber)
    {
        case ValidationSubscribers.Person:
            return new Person();
        case ValidationSubscribers.Checks:
            return new Checks();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Now when you receives an object from this method, you will always have right object.

```
var instanceType = instance.GetCustomAttributes(true); //will give you all attributes
```

You can enhance this logic even further by taking advantage of generic types. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104297/what-are-the-use-cases-of-having-new-in-public-t-somemethodtstring-item-w). However it depends how you design your entities, accordingly you can come up with better solution.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to make *overloads* for each type that you want to validate:

```
void ValidateWithAttributes(Person p, Attribute[] attr) {
    ...
}
void ValidateWithAttributes(Checks c, Attribute[] attr) {
    ...
}
// Add an overload to catch unexpected types
void ValidateWithAttributes(Object obj, Attribute[] attr) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        $"Found an object of unexpected type {obj?.GetType()}"
    );
}
```

Now you can cast your object to `dynamic`, and let the runtime perform the dispatch:

```
object instance;
ValidateWithAttributes((dynamic)instance, attributes);
```