# Invalid Cast of Type Constrained C# Generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Targeting .NET 4.0, I'm trying to build the following classes:

```
public class ConfigurationElementCollection<TElement, TParent> 
    where TElement : ParentedConfigElement<TParent>, new() 
    where TParent : class
{
    public TParent ParentElement { get; set; }

    protected ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        //**************************************************
        //COMPILER GIVES TYPE CONVERSION ERROR ON THIS LINE!
        //**************************************************
        return new TElement { ParentCollection = this };
    }
}

public class ParentedConfigElement<TParent> : ConfigurationElement where TParent : class
{
    internal ConfigurationElementCollection<ParentedConfigElement<TParent>, TParent> 
        ParentCollection { get; set; }

    protected TParent Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return ParentCollection != null ? ParentCollection.ParentElement : null;
        }
    }
}
```

As the code comment above indicates, the compiler gives an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Shared.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection<TElement, TParent>' to 'Shared.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection<Shared.Configuration.ParentedConfigElement,TParent>

I don't expect this error, because the compiler also knows that `TElement` is a `Shared.Configuration.ParentedConfigElement<TParent>` due to the generic type constraint I specified.

Still, I figure I will expressly cast the type to get past this issue:

```
(ConfigurationElementCollection<ParentedConfigElement<TParent>,TParent>) this;
```

Unfortunately, I get the same compiler error.  Why is this happening?  What did I do wrong?  And without resorting to `dynamic` types, what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a type `CEC<A, B>` and you trying to assign it to a property of type `CEC<C<A>,B>` which you can't do, in much the same way as `List<string>` cannot be assigned to storage of type `List<object>` even though `string` derives from `object`.

A clean solution without using implicit operators or dynamic is to use an interface:

```
public interface IConfigurationElementCollection<TParentedConfig, TParent> 
    where TParentedConfig : ParentedConfigElement<TParent>
    where TParent : class
{
    TParent ParentElement { get; }
}

public class ConfigurationElementCollection<TElement, TParent> : IConfigurationElementCollection<ParentedConfigElement<TParent>, TParent>
    where TElement : ParentedConfigElement<TParent>, new() 
    where TParent : class
{
    public TParent ParentElement { get; set; }

    protected ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        //**************************************************
        //COMPILER NO LONGER GIVES TYPE CONVERSION ERROR 
        //BECAUSE this IMPLEMENTS THE EXPECTED INTERFACE!
        //**************************************************
        return new TElement { ParentCollection = this };
    }
}

public class ParentedConfigElement<TParent> : ConfigurationElement where TParent : class
{
    internal IConfigurationElementCollection<ParentedConfigElement<TParent>, TParent> 
        ParentCollection { get; set; }

    protected TParent Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return ParentCollection != null ? ParentCollection.ParentElement : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the property in `ParentedConfigElement` is internal, you can also make the interface internal to avoid exposing this implementation detail to any consumers, if that sort of thing is a concern for you.

Comment: It is obnoxious that the generic constraint on CEC<TElement, TParent> connotes exactly the same thing as the interface you provided...and yet the generic constraint feels as though it is being ignored.  Still, I'm very happy you found a way to make this work without using a `dynamic` type.

Comment: But the generic constraint doesn't say the exact same thing as the interface, it just says that the first type argument inherits from `ParentedConfigElement<TParent>`. This means that `TElement` is assignable to `ParentedConfigElement<TParent>` but that inheritance doesn't extend to the type parameters of generic types.

Answer (score 4):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6529618/5071902

```
protected ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
{
    return (TElement)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TElement), this);
}
```

> You will **need** a constructor with this signature, setting the `ParentCollection` property.

You can try using reflection too. Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6529622/5071902

Comment: The Activator.CreateInstance is only needed when there is no default constructor on the target object.  In my example, I do indeed have a default constructor.  It is only a property that I'm initializing...not a constructor parameter.