# cast of generic type fails

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I am unable to cast a generic type to another generic type, besides the cast should be valid

What I want to archive is in short (for `MyModel` implementing `IModel`, and `MyImplementation` implementing `IImplementation`):

```
IImplementation<IModel> implementation = new MyImplementation<MyModel>();
Assert.IsNull(implementation as IImplementation<IModel>);
```

This is a bit confusing, as the type should be valid.

Complete conceptual model:

```
interface IModel {}

class MyModel : IModel {}

interface IImplementation<TModel> where TModel : IModel { }

class MyImplementation<TModel> : IImplementation<TModel>
    where TModel : IModel { }

public void CallRegister()
{
    var implementation = new MyImplementation<MyModel>();
    var instance = CastModel(implementation);
    Assert.IsNotNull(instance); //this assert fails!
}

private object CastModel<TModel>(IImplementation<TModel> implementation) where TModel : IModel
{
    return implementation as IImplementation<IModel>;
}
```

I need this cast to enable me to save multiple `IImplementation`s to the same `Dictionary<Type, IImplementation<IModel>>`, where the key is obtained by doing `typeof(TModel)`. 
To do this type safe I don't want to use a `Dictionary<Type, object>`.

- Why does the cast fail? Are there additional resources to this? Its a similar question to [Invalid Cast of Type Constrained C# Generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514439/invalid-cast-of-type-constrained-c-sharp-generic), but it is not explained why there just that it does not work.
- What is the best way to archive a functionality similar to the dictionary as explained above if this kind of cast is not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of conversion is not allowed for good reasons. Let's take an example where the problem is more obvious. We have the classes `Animal`, `Cat : Animal` and `Dog : Animal`. Now let's do this:

```
List<Animal> list = new List<Cat>(); // Seems to be possible at first glance.
// An now comes the problem:
list.Add(new Dog());    // Seems to be possible as well.
```

But wait! The list is in reality a list of cats! And we are trying to add a dog. Even adding `new Animal()` to `list`, which is statically typed as `List<Animal>`, would not work.

Therefore two types `T<A>` and `T<B>` are not assignment compatible in C#, even if `A` and `B` are!

You need another approach.

---

What you can do is to wrap your dictionary in a class with a generic method having a generic type constraint.

```
public class MyImplementationDict
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _internalDict = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void Add<T>(IImplementation<T> item)
        where T : IModel
    {
        _internalDict.Add(typeof(T), item);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Great answer! The dictionary with constraints is a nice idea and probably my way to go. I only use `Add`, `Remove` and `Get` so it should be fairly easy to do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Though Olivier's answer gets the idea across about why this usually goes wrong, there is a way to make this work in your program.

The feature you want is called *generic interface covariance*. Covariance is the property that if a `Cat` is an `Animal`, then an `IFoo<Cat>` is an `IFoo<Animal>`.

Covariance in C# only works in the following situations:

- The "outer" type is an interface, delegate or array. No classes or structs.
- If an interface or delegate, the type must be marked at compile time as supporting covariance.  Arrays get (unsafe!) covariance for free.
- The "inner" types -- the types that are varying -- are both reference types.  You can't say that an `IFoo<int>` is an `IFoo<object>` even though an `int` is an `object`, because they are not both reference types.

To mark an interface as covariant, you put `out` before the declaration of the type parameter which you wish to allow to vary:

```
interface IImplementation<out TModel> where TModel : IModel { }
```

If you do that, your program will start to work.

**HOWEVER**, `out` is a reminder to you that *covariance is only safe if `T` is used in output positions.*  This is legal:

```
interface I<out T> {
  T M();
}
```

This is not:

```
interface I<out T> {
  void M(T t);
}
```

In the first, T is only passed *out* of things. In the second, it is passed *in*.

In the first scenario, we cannot use covariance to introduce a type hole.  We have an `I<Cat>` and we cast it to `I<Animal>`, and now `M` returns an `Animal`, but that's OK, because we already know that it will return a `Cat`, and a `Cat` is an `Animal`.

But in the second scenario, we have the opposite situation. If we allowed an `I<Cat>` to be converted to `I<Animal>` then we have an `M` that can take a `Turtle`, but the real implementation can only handle `Cat`s.  That's why C# will make this illegal.

So go forth and use covariance, but remember that *you have to certify to the compiler that you want it, and that it is safe under all circumstances*.  If you don't want it, or it is not safe, then you don't get to have covariance, and you'll have to find a different solution to your problem.

Comment: Nice! I will be unable to use covariance in the context this question came up, but I will certainly read up on it, it'll come in handy soon enough. Thanks!

Comment: @FlorianMoser: You're welcome. If this subject interests you, I've written a great many articles on the design and implementation of the feature, which you can find on my old MSDN blog.

Comment: @FlorianMoser: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4318510/1846281) from Eric that explains why in C# arrays are unsafely co-variant.