# Generic type and dynamic type for the same property

Tags: c#, polymorphism, generic-collections

I have the following classes:

```
public interface IClass 
{
   // empty interface
}
```

Two classes implements the interface as a signature only

```
public abstract class TypeA : IClass
{
   ...
}

public abstract class TypeB : IClass
{
   ...
}
```

Then each of them has some concrete classes:

```
public class TypeA_1 : TypeA
{
   ...
}

public class TypeA_2 : TypeA
{
   ...
}

public class TypeB_1 : TypeB
{
   ...
}

public class TypeB_2 : TypeB
{
   ...
}
```

Then I want a model to have a list of object that under `IClass`, but that object will depend on the implementation of two methods.

**When doing ReadMethod**, I want the Model to have a list of TypeA (either TypeA_1 or TypeA_2) which is dynamically determined at run-time.

**When doing WriteMethod**, I want to Model to be a list of TypeB (either TypeB_1 or TypeB2) -- this can be done by using generic type e.g. `public class Model<T> where T : IClass`

```
public class Model
{
   IList<IClass> AListOfObject { get; set; }
}
```

Methods:

```
public Model ReadMethod(int a)
{
   List<IClass> list = null;

   // prepare Model with list of object (different kind based on argument "a")
   if (a == 1) 
   {
      list = new List<TypeA_1>{ ... };    ----- seems to be not working as instantiating different type?
   }
   if (a == 2) 
   {
      list = new List<TypeA_2>{ ... };
   }

   return new Model { AListOfObject = list };
}

public void WriteMethod(Model model)
{
   ...
}
```

Actually how can I define the `Model` that could fulfill this two methods at the same time? If I use generic type, it will fulfill the **WriteMethod**'s need, but it won't work on the **ReadMethod** as it is dynamic.

Am I conceptually wrong to expect one single `Model`? Is it must to be 2 separate `Model`? But all of them are under `IClass`?

Also I'm just a bit confused on the reason why `List<IClass> list = new List<TypeA_1>()` won't work.

Comment: _why `List<IClass> list = new List<TypeA_1>()` won't work._ because `List<T>` is invariant. Try to use `List<IClass> list = new List<IClass>();` and determine `TypeA` or `TypeB` for every list item

Comment: See explanation (2 answers): [cast of generic type fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378173/cast-of-generic-type-fails).