# Invalid name character error while writing in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to write my class in XML file. Here's my Class:

```
    class Version
    {
        string _version;
        bool _showNextTime;
        public Version(string version, bool showNextTime)
        {
            this._version = version;
            this._showNextTime = showNextTime;
        }

        public string LastVersion { get { return _version; } }
        public bool ShowNextTime { get { return _showNextTime; } }
    }
```

And this is my code to write in XML:

```
        Version newVersion = new Version("3.0.1", false);
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Versions.xml"))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Version");
            writer.WriteElementString(newVersion.LastVersion, newVersion.ShowNextTime.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
```

But it throws this error:

```
Invalid name character in '3.0.1'. The '3' character, hexadecimal value 0x33, cannot be included in a name.
```

Trying to run this line:

```
 writer.WriteElementString(newVersion.LastVersion, newVersion.ShowNextTime.ToString());
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: You setting element name to version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write elements with names defined in the property value. [WriteElementString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aex0e7zs(v=vs.110).aspx) takes the name of the element followed by the value.

Instead of this:

```
 writer.WriteElementString(
     newVersion.LastVersion, 
     newVersion.ShowNextTime.ToString());
```

Do this:

```
 writer.WriteElementString("LatestVersion", newVersion.LastVersion);
 writer.WriteElementString("ShowNextTime", newVersion.ShowNextTime.ToString());
```

An alternative method is to use the framework create the XML representation of your class automatically. There are many examples of that available on StackOverflow. For example [Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)