# How to save and read a text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using `C#` and I would like to know how to save and read a file, but I would like to save more informations, so it will be awesome if the saved file will be something like:

> player-level = 1;
>
> player-money = 100;
>
> etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

Example:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void saveScore(int score) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", score);
    }

    void getScore() 
    {
        print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score"));
    }
}
```

Comment: And if I will close the game, all data will be saved?

Comment: @PanaitStudio yes it will be saved.

Answer (score 1):

For writing file in Unity you can use the following code snippet.
It will create or append the text file in the root folder of your project

```
public void WriteToFile(string text)
{
    StreamWriter fileWriter;
    string fileName = GetCurrentWorkingDirectory() + "/" + "myFile.txt";
    if (!File.Exists (fileName)) {
        fileWriter = File.CreateText (fileName);
        fileWriter.WriteLine (text);
        fileWriter.Close ();
            } 
    else 
    {
        fileWriter = File.AppendText(fileName);
        fileWriter.WriteLine (text);
        fileWriter.Close ();
    }
}
```

For Key Value pair writing you can use XML or JSON.
I would prefer JSON.

Comment: If you want to use XML or JSON, you can use C#'s own [XML serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml) or [JSON serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4).