# c# write xml with the help of array

Tags: c#, xml

I was writing xml with c#, and I come up with a very long list of the same function- SetAttribute, wonder if anyone knows a smart way to write this code. I think about making an array but donot know how, anyone know how to write an array for this code?

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration decl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", null);
        doc.AppendChild(decl);
        XmlElement ChatMapper = doc.CreateElement("ChatMapperProject");  
        doc.AppendChild(ChatMapper);
        XmlNode xmldocSelect = doc.SelectSingleNode("ChatMapperProject");
        //Crteate Attribute
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("Title", "");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("Version", "1.5.1.0");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("Author", "");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisColor1Label", "");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisColor1", "#000000");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisStyle1", "---");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisColor2Label", "");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisColor2", "#000000");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisStyle2", "---");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisColor3Label", "");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisColor3", "#000000");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisStyle3", "---");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisColor4Label", "");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisColor4", "#000000");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisStyle4", "---");
```

Comment: why don't you just [Serialize an Object to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml). another [MSDN tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815813) doing the same thing

Comment: because I load one xml and adjust its value and then transform to another format xml, and almost done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code if you need.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration decl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", null);
            doc.AppendChild(decl);
            XmlElement ChatMapper = doc.CreateElement("ChatMapperProject");
            doc.AppendChild(ChatMapper);
            XmlNode xmldocSelect = doc.SelectSingleNode("ChatMapperProject");
            //Crteate Attribute

            Dictionary<String, String> attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();


            attributes.Add("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            attributes.Add("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            attributes.Add("Title", "");
            attributes.Add("Version", "1.5.1.0");
            attributes.Add("Author", "");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisColor1Label", "");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisColor1", "#000000");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisStyle1", "---");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisColor2Label", "");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisColor2", "#000000");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisStyle2", "---");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisColor3Label", "");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisColor3", "#000000");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisStyle3", "---");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisColor4Label", "");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisColor4", "#000000");
            attributes.Add("EmphasisStyle4", "---");


            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> attribute in attributes)
            {
                ChatMapper.SetAttribute(attribute.Key, attribute.Value);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but Could be an array for the attributes.Add as well?

Comment: An array if you use would have to be possibly a 2D array to hold both attribute name and its value. Any specific reason why you would prefer Arrays ??

Comment: I want to make it shorter, smarter.  writing the same time over and over again is not that good...I think

Comment: Since you have the attributes defined, you will have to for once write them off. Be it in an array or in a Dictionary or directly to SetAttributes. Even if you use array, you will have to fill it atleast once and that code will have to be a repetetive one.

Comment: may be a function array is better?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary object for attribute name as key and its value as value.

Run through the dictionary in a loop and add all the attributes.

But like Liam mentioned, its better if you can serialize the object itself, that would be the better solution.

Comment: This answer is correct but needs more details, see [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)