# Need to Convert Complex object into Xml in .Net c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert a complex object into XML data with one root node alone.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, String> response { get; set; }
}
```

I have customer class which contain `Address` and `User` property. I want to convert the `Customer` object into XML data with one root node.

I want the object into below XML format

```
<row>
    <cell cellType="city">Chennai</cell>
    <cell cellType="state">tamilnadu</cell>
    <cell cellType="name">test</cell>
    <cell cellType="id">001</cell>
    <cell cellType="response1">response1</cell>
    <cell cellType="response2">response2</cell>
</row>
```

Comment: Not related by why you using attributes for the name of value? Why not `<city>Chennai</city><state>tamilnadu</state>...` and so on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize an object to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer()
            {
                Address = new Address()
                {
                    city = "Chennai",
                    State = "tamilnadu",
                },
                user = new User()
                {
                    Name = "test",
                    Id = "001",
                    response = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { "response1", "response1"},
                        { "response2", "response2"}
                    }
                }
            };

            XElement row = new XElement("row", new object[] {
                new XElement("cell", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("cellType", "city"),
                    customer.Address.city
                }),
                new XElement("cell", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("cellType", "state"),
                        customer.Address.State
                    }),
                new XElement("cell", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("cellType", "name"),
                        customer.user.Name
                    }),
                new XElement("cell", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("cellType", "id"),
                        customer.user.Id
                    }),
                    customer.user.response.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new XElement("cell", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("cellType",x.Key),
                        x.Value
                    }))
            });

         } 

        //<row>
        //    <cell cellType="city">Chennai</cell>
        //    <cell cellType="state">tamilnadu</cell>
        //    <cell cellType="name">test</cell>
        //    <cell cellType="id">001</cell>
        //    <cell cellType="response1">response1</cell>
        //    <cell cellType="response2">response2</cell>
        //</row>
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public User user { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<String, String> response { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it with basic xml serialization in C#, but you can create dto class to achieve your goal. Use dto like this and map your entities to it:

```
[XmlRoot("row")]
public class RowDto
{
    [XmlElement("cell")]
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}

public class Cell
{
    [XmlAttribute("cellType")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: my object contain the dictionary as well. So how can convert it to xml with one root node

Comment: It depends of what is the key in your responses dictionary