# how to combine and save list of XmlDocument in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of xmldocuments converted from C# objects using Newtonsoft.Json API. I need help in merging/combining and saving the list to a file.

My code looks like below

```
 var xmlDocumentsList = new List<XmlDocument>();
       foreach (var user in users)
        {
           xmlDocumentsList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user),"user"));                
        }
```

I have looked into XmlTextWriter class examples but could not find an example merging the objects and saving them.

The xmlDocumentsList has user items like below

```
<user>  
 <first_name>Test1</first_name>
 <last_name>Test1</last_name>   
</user>

<user>  
 <first_name>Test2</first_name>
 <last_name>Test2</last_name>   
</user>
```

and I am looking the combined file to be like

```
<users>
<user>  
    <first_name>Test1</first_name>
    <last_name>Test1</last_name>    
</user>

<user>  
    <first_name>Test2</first_name>
    <last_name>Test2</last_name>    
</user>
</users>
```

Comment: Do you have to save each `user` as its own xml document?  Are you able to serialize the whole array of `users`?

Comment: I want to combine all the users in a single file.

Comment: You shouldn't need to jump through all those hoops to convert the object to XML.  I would take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16853268/52051  Then once you have a string, you can call File.Write