# Writing and reading XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I've written a setting file in C# as XML

```
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(files);
xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Settings");

xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("launch");
xmlWriter.WriteString("launch tab");
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("some_setting");
xmlWriter.WriteString("empty");
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

And so on, but how to read it back? 
I keep getting errors.

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(files);

xmlReader.ReadStartElement("launch");
textBox1.Text = xmlReader.ReadString();
```

I wish to simply read it back in but getting the error

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'Element 'launch' was not found

Line 1, position 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the many ways to parse an XML file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files?rq=1) for a decent breakdown of the ways), in general I find parsing with an XmlDocument to be more straightforward. For your code it would be something similar to the example below:

```
void CreateXML(string fileName)
{
    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fileName);
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Settings");

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("launch");
    xmlWriter.WriteString("launch tab");
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("some_setting");
    xmlWriter.WriteString("empty");
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    xmlWriter.Close();
}

void ReadXML(string fileName)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(fileName);
    XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("Settings");
    string launchSetting = root.SelectSingleNode("launch").InnerText;
    textBox1.Text = launchSetting;
}
```

If you want to stick with the XmlReader, I haven't used it before but as Alexei says in his answer it appears that you're not reading in the Settings node start (see below).

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(files);

xmlReader.ReadStartElement("Settings");

xmlReader.ReadStartElement("launch");
textBox1.Text = xmlReader.ReadString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read and write using `XmlWriter` must be symmetrical - you are missing reading Settings in your read code.

Note: it may be easier to use serialization to read/write whole objects - [Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)

Comment: Iam at a loss I dont understand. can you code a small example