# How can I serialize a Class to XML

Tags: c#, json, xml

How can I convert this Class into XML ? Or is there any possible way I can convert a JSON String for the same class directly into XML ? I am not getting an idea or a sample code to start with the conversion.

```
public class Contacts
        {
            public Datum[] data { get; set; }
            public Info info { get; set; }
        }
public class Datum
        {
            public Owner Owner { get; set; }
            public object Email { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string currency_symbol { get; set; }
            public string Mailing_Zip { get; set; }
}
 public class Owner
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }

public class Info
        {
            public int per_page { get; set; }
            public int count { get; set; }
            public int page { get; set; }
            public bool more_records { get; set; }
        }
```

Please help in converting the Class to XML or the JSON String based on the above class into an XML directly.

The scenario is that, I am receiving a JSON result from the API and this result needs to be processed in the SQL Server where the datatype has been kept as XML. I am hoping that this can be achieved successfully.

Comment: this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123648/2630817

Comment: you can use Newtonsoft.Json for converting directly from Json to Xaml. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertJsonToXml.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of online resources to convert c# properties in to JSON or XML without any effort , try [this](https://csharp2json.io/) and [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yE8RAl) and JSON to XML converter [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-to-xml-converter.html) too

**Update**
If you wish to convert inside the code try below. p.s (use Json.NET)

```
string json = //set your result JSON from the web API call;

XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "Root");

Console.WriteLine(node.ToString());
```

this will convert your Json to XML

Comment: @IpsitGaur I've Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same converting the JSON to Class object and serializing the XML from the Class object.

```
public static string GetXMLFromObject(object o)
        {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter tw = null;
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
                tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
                serializer.Serialize(tw, o);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle Exception Code
            }
            finally
            {
                sw.Close();
                if (tw != null)
                {
                    tw.Close();
                }
            }
            return sw.ToString();
        }
```