# What is the simplest way to do serialization deserialization for boolean variables in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, boolean, deserialization

I have a flag class,(and a simple button to change the flag values) when I **stop and restart the program** I want to see the changed boolean variables. I did my search on it and I am kind of lost. 
Right now I have a constructor but I couldn't figure how to use it with save/load functions.

What is the simplest way to do it?

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.ComponentModel;
> using System.Data;
> using System.Drawing;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Text;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
> using System.IO;
> using System.Collections;
> using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
> using System.Runtime.Serialization;
> using System.Xml.Serialization;
> using System.Xml;
> ```

```
namespace SaveReloadDeneme
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool flag;
        bool flag2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            flag = false;
            flag2 = false;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flag = true;
            flag2 = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Flag changed: " + flag);
            Console.WriteLine("Flag2 changed: " + flag2);
        }



        void SaveData()
        {
            // Create a hashtable of values that will eventually be serialized.
            Hashtable addresses = new Hashtable();
            addresses.Add(1, flag);


            // To serialize the hashtable and its key/value pairs,   
            // you must first open a stream for writing.  
            // In this case, use a file stream.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

            // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            try
            {
                formatter.Serialize(fs, addresses);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }


        public void LoadData()
        {
            // Declare the hashtable reference.
            Hashtable addresses = null;

            // Open the file containing the data that you want to deserialize.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                // Deserialize the hashtable from the file and  
                // assign the reference to the local variable.
                addresses = (Hashtable)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
           }
        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
}

static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.SaveData();
            f.LoadData(); 

        }
```

When I open the **".dat"** file, it is gibberish and I think does not contain the current saved value of the flag.

Comment: I'd suggest using JSON. It is simple, easy and reasonably human readable.

Comment: @mjwills okay I'll try with JSON

Comment: Looking at your code, it's probably not an serialization problem but rather a misunderstanding of how the initialization of your program works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialization and deserialization looks fine. But in your `Main()` method, you first **save** the data and than **reload** the saved (default) data. So you overwrite the saved data.
Adapting your code would give:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);        
        Form1 newForm = new Form1();           
        newForm.LoadData(); 
        Application.Run(newForm);
    }
```

You also save the data before it is changed. 
The **SaveData()** method would be better before closing the application. So extending or previous code would be:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);  
    Form1 newForm = new Form1();           
    newForm.LoadData(); 
    Application.ApplicationExit += (o, e) => newForm.SaveData();      
    Application.Run(newForm );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it saves the results in ".dat" file but I can not see it, do you know how to display in a proper format, otherwise I can not see the saved value.

Comment: Click the button, close your form and restart it. What is the outcome? You can place a breakpoint after the deserializing (after  `addresses = (Hashtable)formatter.Deserialize(fs);`) and see the result by hovering `adresses`.

Comment: You can serialize to XML. It is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663848/2100994) anwer.

Answer (score 1):

As mjwils said, JSON could be a good option.

[Here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm)  are some axamples.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{

    public class Movie
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Movie movie = new Movie
        {
            Name = "Bad Boys",
            Year = 1995
        };

        // serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file
        string json =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        File.WriteAllText("your.path.here", json);

        string json2 = File.ReadAllText("your.path.here");
        Movie movie2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(movie2.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code it does not perform the deserialize part. It writes to txt but when I close and open the program flags are not updated. Movie2 is not used says the compiler

Comment: @Deniz it is an example how you can write a serialized object to a file, you should replace Movie class with your data (flags in this case).