# How to serialize List<T> pp to XML?

Tags: c#, xml

How to serialize `List<T> pp` to XML?

```
var pp = new List<T>();

if (reader.HasRows) 
{

    Console.WriteLine("{0} \t{1} \t{2}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2));

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var obj = new T();
        obj.S = reader.GetString(0);
        obj.S1 = reader.GetString(1);
        obj.S2 = reader.GetInt32(2);
        obj.S3 = reader.GetString(3);

        pp.Add(obj);

    }
}
```

How to serialize `List<T> pp` to XML?

Comment: Did you try the top answer from [Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123648)?  It should work for your `List<T>`.

Comment: as times sit try )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for a Solution below is the Code

```
XmlSerializer xsGList = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>),
                               new XmlRootAttribute("Ts"));
 var subReq = new List<T>(); // assign the value
 subReq=pp; 
 var xml = "";

 using(var stream = new StringWriter())
 {
  using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
  {
     xsGList.Serialize(writer, subReq);
     xml = stream.ToString(); // Your XML as string
  }
 }
```

Comment: You must statically cache and reuse an `XmlSerializer` constructed with an `new XmlRootAttribute("Ts")` override.  For why see [Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182).