# How can i save my Objects and Display them using XML instead of .txt?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How can I save all my Data into a Local XML File? I want to be able to load, save and edit different Students. 
I used .txt file to save all the data in combination with Json, however I now would like to swap to XML.
How would I do that?

Cheers

PS: I'm using C# Visual Studio

````
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string FilePath = (@"d:\Entwicklung\dotNET\HKC\Übungsaufgaben\WindowsFormsApp2\StudentList.txt");
        BindingList<Student> StudentCollection = new BindingList<Student>();

        private void btnLaden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Student StudentLoad = (Student)cbxStudentIDs.SelectedItem;

            txtStudentID.Text = StudentLoad.ID;
            txtFirstName.Text = StudentLoad.FirstName;
            txtLastName.Text = StudentLoad.LastName;
            txtSchoolClass.Text = StudentLoad.Schoolclass;
            nudAge.Value = StudentLoad.Age;
            nudHeight.Value = StudentLoad.Height;
            cbxGender.Text = StudentLoad.Gender;
        }

        private void btnAddStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Student StudentSave = new Student
            {
                ID = txtStudentID.Text,
                FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
                LastName = txtLastName.Text,
                Age = nudAge.Value,
                Height = nudHeight.Value,
                Schoolclass = txtSchoolClass.Text,
                Gender = cbxGender.Text,
            };

            cbxStudentIDs.DataSource = StudentCollection;
            cbxStudentIDs.DisplayMember = "ID";
            StudentCollection.Add(item: StudentSave);

        }

        public class Student
        {
            //Eigenschaften
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public decimal Age { get; set; }
            public decimal Height { get; set; }
            public string Schoolclass { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string studentCollectionString = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindingList<Student>>(studentCollectionString)?.ToList().ForEach(a => StudentCollection.Add(a));
            cbxStudentIDs.DataSource = StudentCollection;
            cbxStudentIDs.DisplayMember = "ID";
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            string studentCollectionString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(StudentCollection);
            File.WriteAllText(FilePath, studentCollectionString);
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like below.  Fill the instances students.students with data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            Students students = new Students();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Students));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, students);

        }

        public class Students
        {
            [XmlElement("Students")]
            public List<Student> students { get; set; }

        }
        public class Student
        {
            //Eigenschaften
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public decimal Age { get; set; }
            public decimal Height { get; set; }
            public string Schoolclass { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? I dont really know anything about XML and its super confusing. Cheers

Comment: Xml Serializtion will take the classes and create xml with no other steps required except the code that is posted.  So all yo have to do is to add the data to the list :  public List<Student> students { get;set;}