# Adding XML attribute to an element

Tags: c#, xml

Looking to add an attribute to an existing xml element `<D_COMMS>`, not replace the existing attribute just add it to the beginning.

This is the XML

```
<OUTPUT version="2.0">
 <RESPONSE>
  <DATA id="17fb13cca6c5463597fdf340c044069f">
    <![CDATA[<ID> jdfkldklfjdkl</ID><D_COMMS>ON this date...</D_COMMS>]]>
  </DATA>
 </RESPONSE>
```

This XML is the result of a HTTPWebResponse so this is what the XMl looks like when it comes back to me and I need to add a value to the D_COMMS element and send it back.Tried something like this to look for the descendant DATA and add it that way.

```
var addelement = doc.Descendants("DATA").First();
addelement.Add(XElement("D_COMMS","On this date we said"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the DATA node and add an attribute as follows:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNodeList dataNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DATA");
if (dataNodes != null && dataNodes.Count > 1)
{
    dataNodes[0].Attributes.Append(doc.CreateAttribute("D_COMMS", "On this date we said"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A better one to set attribute is in here [Adding attributes to an XML node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882143/adding-attributes-to-an-xml-node)

```
    XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("id");
    id.SetAttribute("userName", "Tushar");
```